# zfs snapshots only when different from last snapshot

Tags: zfs

How can I arrange snap shoting such that a snap is only done if the area to be snapped is actually different from last snap of that area?

Answer (score 2):

Given that ZFS snapshots are cheap in terms of computation and storage, and certainly faster than doing a diff between the live situation and the previous snapshot, I would:

1. Make new snapshot
2. Use `zfs diff` to compare the new and previous snapshot
3. If no difference, destroy the new snapshot

Comment: Good answer - a snapshot identical to the previous one takes virtually no space (except a tiny amount of metadata). I wouldn't even consider it necessary to bother about doing this, but if the OP insists.

Comment: @ArturMeinild agreed, I would keep the intermediate snapshot too, if only because it ascertains the state of affairs at that point in time, which you couldn't be sure of if you had only the snapshots before and after it. Was the snapshot actually taken and when did the change occur? But it seems the OP has lost interest.